# Force instalation/reqire antivirus in Group Policy

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I have to force instalation or somehow let user know that he should install NOD antivirus o his computer. In our company, we all have notebook with one local admin account and account from Active Directory. For usual work is used AD profile . I'd like to achieve for example forbid user to login until he installs NOD or install it before actual login if he doesn't have it.

Does somebody how to? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to achieve for example forbid user to login until he installs NOD or install it before actual login if he doesn't have it.

Why are you leaving the configuration of your end-user computers up to the user? You should be using a configuration management tool, such as System Center Configuration Manager, to actively deploy required software and report on configuration baselines.

At the very least, deploying via Group Policy Software Deployment can at least ensure that you cover the majority of users in your organization with a specific piece of software, though it is very poor for auditing failed installations and has no reporting for current configuration.

Comment: I started to work for small company where I'm that guy which brings changes. However, policy here is on "trust" basis. Security and administrative nightmare man... Anyway, thank you for response.